# What is the role of stratospheric water vapor emissions in climate change?

Tags: climate-change, atmosphere, water-vapour, stratosphere

Water vapor is the most significant greenhouse gas in the Earth's atmosphere. However, tropospheric water vapor has a short atmospheric half-life. Therefore, anthropogenic surface-level water vapor emissions are generally not considered to significantly contribute to climate change.

On the other hand, stratospheric water vapor has a much longer half-life. Anthropogenic emission sources of stratospheric water include exhaust gases from aviation. What is the current scientific understanding of the significance of these emissions? How much do they contribute compared to other anthropogenic greenhouse gas emissions? How much do they contribute compared to CO<sub>2</sub> emissions from aviation? Is the contribution different on shorter and longer timescales?